# Artifactory API - devopshq/artifactory

Tags: python, artifactory

https://github.com/devopshq/artifactory

Trying to use this package, but can't because of the following error

```py
from artifactory import ArtifactoryPath

artifactoryPath: ArtifactoryPath = ArtifactoryPath(
    "https://artifactory.company.com/artifactory/some_repo",
    apikey="super secret api key",
    )

for p in artifactoryPath.glob("**/some-package*.zip"):
    print(p)
```

and I get this error when I run this script

```
[WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'https://artifactory.company.com/artifactory/some_repo'
```

I don't understand the callstack

```
File "C:\Users\admin\Work\\MyArtifactory.py", line 23, in __init__
  for p in artifactoryPath.glob("**/some-package*.zip"):
File "C:\Users\admin\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.11.2\Lib\pathlib.py", line 953, in glob
  for p in selector.select_from(self):
File "C:\Users\admin\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.11.2\Lib\pathlib.py", line 408, in _select_from
  for p in successor_select(starting_point, is_dir, exists, scandir):
File "C:\Users\admin\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.11.2\Lib\pathlib.py", line 355, in _select_from
  with scandir(parent_path) as scandir_it:
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\admin\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.11.2\Lib\pathlib.py", line 938, in _scandir
  return os.scandir(self)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'https://artifactory.company.com/artifactory/some_repo'
```

Obviously "'https://artifactory.company.com/artifactory/some_repo'" is not a windows path, hence the error. I also inspected `artifactory.py` - https://github.com/devopshq/artifactory/blob/master/artifactory.py#L1468, it inherits from `pathlib.Path` so that's why it's going directly and calling the actual filesystem `Path` methods (when I call the `glob` method)?

I am wondering if you any of you fine folks can give me some pointers on making this work. TIA

Comment: How about if you just do the filtering as you iterate over the contents? eg `path = ArtifactoryPath(...); for p in path: m = re.search(pattern, str(p))`